# Azure Durable Entity cannot be reached anymore , seems like signals are being queued and not read

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using Azure Durable Functions and have this running in production.  All goes well, but for one specific entity, it seems I can no longer reach that entity anymore.

Signals, Calls... Everything seems to be ignored.  And when using the DFM (Durable Functions Monitor), I remember seeing something like queue depth (or queue length) that was rather high.

So, I get the impression that the entity is somewhat "orphaned".  But I don't know how to fix it.

- I would be happy to clear that queue and lose any existing signals.  How could I do this?
- I would even be happy to clear/remove that entity, but even that does not seem possible, as I have only found to clear state of an entity from inside an entity itself.
- Is there any troubleshooting tips someone can give?

Thanks for any tips,

Sam

Comment: you'd better open an issue on Github with some screenshots too

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1826) (which declared to be fixed in v2.6.1)?